# Align text and image vertically in QML Text when using html tag with given height and width

Tags: html, qt, qml

Following is the QML text. When I am giving width and height to the image, it is not vertically aligned with the text. But without specifying height and width both are vertically aligned.

```
Text
 {
text: '<p>  <div> <h2>Hello</h2> <img style="vertical-align: middle" ; src="image.png" width="30"      height="30" > </div></p>'
textFormat : Text.RichText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find something like this works if you're able to use flex.

```
<p>  
  <div id="vertical-container"> 
    <h2>Hello</h2> 
    <img src="image.png" width="30" height="30" > 
  </div>
</p>
<style>

  #vertical-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
       -moz-box-orient: vertical;
       -moz-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
       -moz-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
  }

</style>
```

Which converts over to:

```
Text
{
   text: '<p>  
   <div id="vertical-container"> 
     <h2>Hello</h2> 
     <img src="image.png" width="30" height="30" > 
   </div>
  </p>
  <style>

  #vertical-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
       -moz-box-orient: vertical;
       -moz-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
       -moz-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  </style>'
  textFormat : Text.RichText
}
```

Refer [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to see the browser support for flex.